# Why typescript type guarding doesn't work in this example?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

My example is the following code:

```js
type SomeType = {
    name: string,
    age: number,
} | {
    xy: [number, number]
}


function someFunction(arg: SomeType) {
    if (arg.name && arg.age) {
        // DO STH
    } else if (arg.xy) {
        // DO STH
    }
}
```

Why typescript shows me the following error messages?

When hovering on `arg.xy`
[image]

When hovering on `arg.name` or `arg.age`:
[image]

Comment: I would say the error message is not completely accurate, but the warning tells you that you can not be sure to reference this property. If you have a type "any", you would also refer to name with `arg['name']` instead of arg.name even if you know that it exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have a union of types, you can only access properties that exist on *all* of the types. So for example you can't access `name`, because `{ xy: [number, number] }` doesn't have a `name` property.

Instead, use the `in` operator to check whether the property exists:

```
if ("name" in arg) {
  // in this block, arg is narrowed to being { name: string, age: number }
} else {
  // in this block, arg is narrowed to being { xy: [number, number ] }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFA3gWAFBSFQB2AhkgFxQDOwATgJbEDmANPkVKcxFcQK4IARhDrs8AXygAfbByIAPEFQDaA4aNYlBIugF18E-MbwAzfsQDGwBnGI1EEAGIXrt4gApSdZlXhJUSABKOQIoBlMoDwAiMiRo8PtvZhDcMMIAegzEqGAACwZqKCEAGzhLAGstZPCisjo6OAB3CAATXLhiiCZmbBJyXhp6HuqePh1RKCN0qEs7ajgSiAA6MuYvH2XuCCCAbnkpCBLqaDTOLJz8wuKyyuqfWv6G5raOrp6%20pVV1XS0fyb0U3khDmxAWS1WcHWyWWSj2B0MQA)

Another option is to change your types so that you have a discriminated union. Ie, you have a certain property that exists on *all* members of the union, but each individual type has a different value for it. Since all the types have it, you can always access it. And since it's unique, checking it can tell you what you're dealing with.

```
type Example = {
  type: 'person',
  name: string,
  age: number,
} | {
  type: 'coordinate',
  xy: [number, number]
}

function someFunction (arg: Example) {
  if (arg.type === 'person') {
    // do something with the person object
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQN4FgBQUUokAXFAOSQBOAzgPYB2FANAUY8hObcNQJaMA5m0JQEQ7lEYBXJACMI1UQF8oAHxzti4KRQDG9etQAmghMAittcEOQDashUpbS5i6gF0CKggQBmMoz6wPxMUAxIEABiQSFhjFAAFAjUQuTwyGgQAJRaYvz%20yalCAHQkmBhYVEoMzHl4YkQA9M1QJvQR9FHAABaCQlAA7vx9xL3QNHVQ9PIAVhAh2kSGjAzopaj0QilppZxROQDc2r74KkA)

Comment: Thank you very much! Even though its weird that there is a difference between ```"property" in object``` and ```Boolean(object.property)```.